# Starting Apache on Ubuntu 16.04: service doesn't and apache2ctl does work

Tags: 16.04, apache2, services, autostart

I'm running Apache with a fairly custom configuration.

I noticed that `service apache2 start` and `systemctl start apache2.service` don't work, while `apache2ctl start` works fine.

The error message from `systemctl status apache2.service` is "The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds." but I'm pretty sure it does when I use apache2ctl. Strangely the Apache process is started after the error and the website works fine. I just can't use the commands again to stop or reload...

How can i debug why the first two don't work ? How do they determine if Apache has started ?

Comment: To check apache is running `sudo systemctl list-units | grep apache2`

Comment: @George: systemctl list-units said "loaded failed failed    LSB: Apache2 web server", but i knew it thought it failed to load from "systemctl status apache2". But in fact it is running fine...

Comment: If that's the case I advice you re-install, completely purge it and re-install. Cause `apache2ctl` can't be saying on thing and `systemctl` another!

Comment: Are there anything in the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file? Also, what's the ouptut of `journalctl -xe`? Please edit into your question the full error log that you get when you try to start/restart apache and it fails (and anything related you can find in the log file and with `journalctl -xe` ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apache2.conf had a line

```
PidFile /var/run/httpd2.pid
```

but Ubuntu 16.04 expects the pid file to appear as `/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid`.

So my Apache started well, but the apache_wait_start() function in `/etc/init.d/apache2` that gets used by `service apache2 start` never saw a pid file and thought the process didn't start.

`apache2ctl` apparently doesn't check if there is a pid file (or maybe reads the apache2.conf where it is).

After fixing the filename, all runs well now.